# How to replace multiple occurrence of a pattern in str_replace_all?

Tags: r, str-replace, stringr

I am trying to replace parenthesis with "." in the string "abc(def)ghi".
The code used is following:

```
str_replace_all("abc(def)ghi", "\\)|\\)", ".")
```

The output is `"abc(def.ghi"`.

.

The desire output should be `"abc.def.ghi"` .

Any easy way to achieve this in R?

Comment: you have `)` two times. Do `str_replace_all("abc(def)ghi", "\\(|\\)", ".")`

Comment: Thanks. apology for typos. I should be more careful

Answer (score 4):

You can use this snippet:

```
str_replace_all("abc(def)ghi", "[()]", ".")
```

Comment: Thanks. apology for typos. I should be more careful